# get column names from query result using pymssql

Tags: python, database, pymssql

Is there any way to get the column names from the pymssql results?  If i specify as_dict=True I get back a dictionary, which does contain all the column headers, but since it is a dictionary they are not ordered.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

pymssql claims to support the Python [DB-API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), so you should be able to get the `.description` attribute from your cursor object.

> .description
>
> ```
>        This read-only attribute is a sequence of 7-item
>        sequences.  
>
>        Each of these sequences contains information describing
>        one result column: 
>
>          (name, 
>           type_code, 
>           display_size,
>           internal_size, 
>           precision, 
>           scale, 
>           null_ok)
> ```

So, the first item in each of the "inner" sequences is the name for each column.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a list of ordered column names using list comprehension on the cursor description attribute:

```
column_names = [item[0] for item in cursor.description]
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the column names on a single comma separated line.

```
colNames = ""
for i in range(len(cursor.description)):
    desc = cursor.description[i]
        if i == 0:
            colNames = str(desc[0])
        else:
            colNames += ',' + str(desc[0])
        print colNames
```

Alternatively, pass the column names to a list and use .join to get them as string.

```
colNameList = []
    for i in range(len(cursor.description)):
        desc = cursor.description[i]
        colNameList.append(desc[0])

        colNames = ','.join(colNameList)
        print colNames
```

Comment: really the python way to do it is ",".join(cursor.description)

Comment: .description is a list of 7-item tuples so ",".join(cursor.description) won't do it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a basic solution and need optimizing but the below example returns both column header and column value in a list.

```
import pymssql

def return_mssql_dict(sql):
    try:

        con = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, database_name)
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql)

        def return_dict_pair(row_item):
            return_dict = {}
            for column_name, row in zip(cur.description, row_item):
                return_dict[column_name[0]] = row
            return return_dict

        return_list = []
        for row in cur:
            row_item = return_dict_pair(row)
            return_list.append(row_item)

        con.close()

        return return_list

    except Exception, e:
        print '%s' % (e)
```